# Can we rethink requesting MathJaX?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, formatting

I know this has already [been brought up](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/690/5705) and (sort of) rejected, but that was over a year ago and I think it deserves a new discussion.

Computer graphics is an inherently mathematical subject (we do even have a [mathematics](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics) tag).  As raytracing, shading, and procedural textures are some of my specialties I regularly write questions and answers dealing with vectors and other heavily mathematical topics.  So I often find myself wishing I could include prettyprint mathematical typesetting in my answers.

Currently I usually include mathematical equations by either typing them single-file in code blocks or doing the typesetting in MS Word or Mathematica and taking a screenshot.  Both of these are horribly inefficient and/or hard to read.

So here are my questions:

- Does anyone else think being able to natively typeset mathematical expressions would be valuable to Blender.SE?
- What would be required to enable MathJaX mathematical typesetting for Blender.SE?
- Why would we *not* want MathJaX?
- Do we even still have the option of adding new features now that we have graduated?

Comment: This was eventually implemented in 2018, per [this post](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2453/131311).

Answer (score 6):

I'll answer your bullet points in order.

> Does anyone else think being able to natively typeset mathematical expressions would be valuable to Blender.SE?

**Yes** I asked for it originally, and still think it would be useful.

> What would be required to enable MathJaX mathematical typesetting for Blender.SE?

The SE devs set all that up, from our perspective not much. They just add a library ([MathJax](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax)) and a bit of js.

> Why would we *not* want MathJaX?

The overhead of adding another library to load. It can make pages slower, and the rendering of the math can be slower still.
For 90ish% of our questions it would do nothing.

> Do we even still have the option of adding new features now that we have graduated?

**Sure**! There is a [feature-request](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag just for asking for things like this; and the meta is the place to suggest them. If you look at SE's [update log](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/278094) they are always changing things.

Comment: The overhead in loading MathJax seems *trivial.* It also renders fairly fast in most browsers. "If taken from the MathJax CDN, the actual (compressed) data transferred for MathJax.js will be about 14.4KB. [...]minimal configurations can be as small as 3.7KB." see 1st para of http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/misc/faq.html

Comment: When you need it - it's incredibly useful. There is math everywhere in Blender ([e.g.](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/44783/5334)) and yet right now it's hard to write enough of an equation to talk/ask/answer about it.

Comment: I needed it today [for this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/64485/5334) so I used it in another stackexchange site and then pasted a screenshot.