# I could really use MathJax for a series of questions - how to build support for it?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, formatting, mathjax

I use blender to illustrate and demonstrate physics and optics, and it's incredibly useful. Blender + Python is a winning combination for science.

I'd like to ask several questions, and they involve math. Here is [a question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/64485/5334) where I would have used MathJax for example. Instead I posted a screenshot from another Stackexchange site where I could use it.

The natural language for mathematics is not ASCII, it's equations, and MathJax support in many Stackexchange sites is widely used and appreciated. This [MathJax in Stackexchange](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial is helpful, but you can just edit any question or answer with an existing equation to see how it works.

If I understand correctly, if MathJax is turned on in a given Stackexchange site, it doesn't actually affect the user experience unless viewing a question/answer that requires it - it doesn't download until needed. But I am not sure about this. Is this true?

What would be needed to build a consensus that activating MathJax support for this Stackexchange site is a good idea? Are there any down sides?

There was a previous request [here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/690/5334) that has gone unanswered, and [the answer](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2197/5334) to the question "Can we rethink requesting MathJaX?" seems to be quite positive.

Comment: I personally have no use for it, and have no real idea about the consequences or possible performance concerns it may raise. My guess is that there never was enough interest or momentum to actually implemented it, but if it does helps some users and there are no downsides, then I'd vote to add.

Comment: Right, with the technical shift in our scope I could see this being used more. Will poke someone.

Comment: So it seems this is possible but we have to do a bit of investigating first, posts that could get broken, existing posts than will benefit from this and examples of future questions etc. Consider this in progress.

Comment: @iKlsR OK that's great to hear! If there is anything I can do to help somehow let me know. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: @uhoh The more examples of existing questions/answers that we can compile the better.

Comment: @iKlsR oh, OK how to proceed? Search for questions that contain words that might be math related? I've never done it before but there are python API's out there for stackexchange searches, and I think stackexchange has its own scripted search utility. Is this the kind of thing you mean?

Comment: @uhoh Right, examples like these http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/690/enable-mathjax-syntax

Comment: @iKlsR OK that's actually something I can do. OK maybe a few days to learn how to best do the search.

Comment: Related: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2196/can-we-rethink-requesting-mathjax?noredirect=1&lq=1 and http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/690/enable-mathjax-syntax.  (BTW I am *heavily* in favor of this proposal.)

Comment: @iKlsR Where should said list be compiled?  Should we make a community wiki meta post for it?

Comment: @PGmath that's an excellent idea - I don't know how to create one, but if you (or someone) starts I will contribute. It could use a bit of organization - not just a list of 101 questions, but broken down somehow so there are several good examples in each category. But I don't know what the categories should exactly be. Fudged equations, screen shots, fails, workarounds, questions that could have been better if... dunno. What do you think?

Comment: @PGmath we can do so right here. Just post whatever you deem useful in a general answer below similar to our resources posts.

Comment: @uhoh I'll bump this up the chain again thanks for the effort.

Comment: I am strongly in favor of MathJax support. As someone who usually write technical answer, not having MathJax resolve me to either compile Latex or screenshot MathJax rendered equation from some online site or a local page which takes some time.

Comment: @iKlsR Is this still going to happen? What still needs to be done?

Comment: Yikes, nearly a year. I'll contact a community manager again. @ScottMilner

Comment: Ok the ball has finally started rolling. We can expect an official reply from StackExchange as early as a couple weeks (hopefully this month). Thanks for being patient.

Comment: @iKlsR that's great news, thank you! If there's any thing I can do to help, let me know!

Comment: @uhoh More examples would help as we find them. Omar's posts are especially helpful.

Comment: It's taking us a bit longer to get to this, but it is on our radar!

Comment: You might find this discussion interesting: https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/45/34

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for your patience. ***Yes, we will enable MathJax on Blender.SE!***

The one real catch is that enabling MathJax will break the formatting on a few posts. I looked into the situation (query [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/blender/query/804618)), and there are only ~20 posts which have in-line `$` delimiters. Workable enough, but folks around these parts will still need to be willing to do a little manual editing to update these posts.

All you gotta do is add a `\` in front of the `$` on any of the broken posts. I included an example screenshot below from Math.SE (where MathJax is enabled) to show what I mean.

[image]

Some SE communities have also created their own specialized guides to working with MathJax. You can see examples of those [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288209/238110), in case you want to create one of your own.

### Update: MathJax is now on!

Comment: Yay! For a general guide to MathJax in SE I use this: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/284619

Comment: I have gone through all of the posts on the query. Everything should be fixed. The remaining posts that come up have `$`'s in code blocks, so they aren't an issue.

Comment: Are we encouraged to edit in MathJax to posts of other users?

Comment: @ScottMilner Yikes! Thank you. I was just prepared to do some late night edits. Definitely, as a holder of the edit posts privilege we trust your judgement when to use it! :)

Comment: I'd also recommend anyone with the time to create *our* own fancy mathjax guide. Could be a copy-paste from an existing one with credits. Would be great to feature and point new users to here!

Comment: Congrats to all those who lobbied for this.

Comment: I just tried MathJax here, updated most of my answers. There is a certain behavior that I would like to change, empty lines causes Mathjax to stop rendering, this seems to be similar to math.SE, is there a way around this? Also, upon editing a post with MathJax equations, it stops rendering until page is reloaded.

Answer (score 14):

In accordance with [iKlsR's comment](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2222/i-could-really-use-mathjax-for-a-series-of-qestions-how-to-build-support-for-i#comment4947_2222), here is a list of posts which would benefit from MathJaX.  Anyone and everyone is encouraged to add to it as you like.

---

**Update:** Now that MathJax is turned on, please update this list to show which posts have been successfully converted.

---

<s>Question [How to understand the math behind Andrew Price's embedding his beer within his glass](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64485/how-to-understand-the-math-behind-andrew-prices-embedding-his-beer-within-his-g)</s>
<s>Question [Physical iridescence in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/82705/26640)</s>
<s>Question [Plotting 3D Regions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/90331/26640)</s>
<s>Question [Plotting 3D Surfaces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/90357/26640)</s>
<s>Question [Math logic between camera angle and lens](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/95089/26640)</s>
Question [How to create a 3D object from a specific equation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/80110/26640)
<s>Question [how to change a mesh given by mathematical function with time i.e. how to include the time parameter in the mathematical equation?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/87390/26640)</s>
<s>Question (and answers of) [How to: Exponential Fall Off for Volume Density?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/92209/26640)</s>
<s>Question [How can I generate an object from a mathematical function?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/63697/26640)</s>
<s>Question [Creating mesh on a surface with two variables](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/79521/26640)</s>
<s>Question (and answers of) [Blender Cycle's z-coordinate vs. camera-centered z-coordinate (orthogonal distance)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/87504/26640)</s>
<s>Question [How to calculate Specular value for Principled BSDF node from IOR?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/84885/26640)</s>
<s>Question [creating mesh on an isosurface](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/79576/26640)</s>
<s>Question [particle simulation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/79826/26640)</s>
<s>Question [Write the Rotation Matrix Values of an Object by XYZ individually?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/94559/26640)</s>
<s>Question [blender camera from 3x4 matrix](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/40650/26640)</s>
<s>Question [Animation nodes: rotate around axis](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/97443/26640)</s>
<s>Question [3x4 camera matrix from blender camera](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/38009/26640)</s>

<s>Answer to [Detect light amount on surface?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/29094/2217)</s>
<s>Answer to [How can I create a staggered, repeating procedural pattern?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28870/2217)</s>
<s>Answer to [Modeling a Klein bottle](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18956/2217)</s>
<s>Answer to [Affecting a material based on another object's relation to camera](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/62345/5705)</s>
<s>Answer to [Possible to control a Driver from a Group Node input slider?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/40829/5705)</s>
<s>Answer to [Is it possible to render a panorama in perspectives other than full 360°x180°?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18593/5705)</s>
<s>Answer to [How does the Turbulence Force Field work?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/68777/5705)</s>
<s>Answer to [Liquid / glass interface IOR and normals in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2824/5334)</s>
<s>Answers to [What is Dot Product?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/47523/5705)</s>
<s>Answer to [Matcaps and Normal Stretching](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/76789/26640)</s>
<s>Answer to [In BGE is there a way to apply gravity to the inside of a sphere](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/90831/26640)</s>
<s>Answer to [Trace visualisation in 3D - how to wrap curves onto a 3D mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/95577/26640)</s>
<s>Answer to [Build color ramp out of math nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/44565/26640)</s>
<s>Answer to [What does the “unused” output on the Vector Math node do?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/62339/26640)</s>
<s>Answer to [What does the “Absolute” setting in the Math node do?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/41167/26640)</s>
<s>Answer to [How to construct a pyramid in blender but the edges of the triangles to be equal?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/11076/26640)</s>
<s>Answer to [Possible to use object speed/acceleration as driver variable?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/66136/26640)</s>
<s>Answer to [How to make a node group to calculate fresnel via F0 values](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/73204/26640)</s>
<s>Answer to [How to achieve this spline and particle effect](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/93115/26640)</s>
<s>Answer to [Creating Normal maps from a Texture?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/63102/26640)</s>
<s>Answer to [Understanding 3D transforms and rotations](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8323/26640)</s>
<s>Answer to [What do glossy distribution models do?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/40744/26640)</s>
<s>Answer to [Camera angle for 50% height hex grid](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41629/26640)</s>
<s>Answer to [Acces unmodified Normals on object with Custom/Transferred normals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/100463/26640)</s>

---

#### Possible Benefit<sup>†</sup>:

Question [How do you create a Math Formula for a Model Object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/52837/26640)
Question (and answers of) [functioning of the geometry node- what does it do with the vector math](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/79591/26640)
Question [How to simply find the code/script behind the volume scatter node so I can see the math?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/77085/26640)
Question [How to make variable transparency hole in a plane with a math function using nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/67672/26640)
Question [Clarifying Blender skeleton animation and OpenGL](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/31254/26640)
Question [How to set a given Island margin for UV?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/89893/26640)

Answer to [how are the math node operations in cycles calculated?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/45094/26640)

<sub>† The math in these posts might fit better remaining as pseudocode than being converted to MathJaX.</sub>

---

Note that there are currently 129 questions tagged with [mathematics](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics), a huge portion of these would probably benefit from MathJaX.  Keep in mind though that these are not the *only* posts which would, as there are many math-based answers.

Comment: Super thanks to Scott Milner for taking the initiative to update these posts!