# Proposing the numpy tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Have proposed the `numpy` tag.

Currently searching on `numpy` yields 423 results and `numpy [python]` 322 so there is some interest.  Not that all of these would be tagged, some IMO would benefit

[Replace matrix @ vector list comprehensions with something more efficient](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139511/replace-matrix-vector-list-comprehensions-with-something-more-efficient)

Has been my experience asking Blender related `numpy`  questions on  [SO](https://stackoverflow.com) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com) often generate little or no interest.

*Asked this one*

[Indexing back to the one from the many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66407635/indexing-back-to-the-one-from-the-many)

*in relation to [selecting verts using UVs selected](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/212287/select-everything-inside-the-uv-0-1/212840#212840)*

*I knew what I wanted to achieve Blender wise,  coming up with the numpy jargon to ask a good question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com) not so much.  IMO Blender related `numpy` questions will help bridge that divide for all, and in the end help us produce faster code when dealing with large arrays (like a mesh)*

To reiterate: Tagged questions would be about solving a blender specific question using `numpy`. The python bundled with Blender includes `numpy`. (*It hasn't always*)  On the con side I understand there are many other python modules shipped with Blender & why add just one as a tag.

Anyway will leave it at this. Interested to hear your thoughts.

Comment: Well I'm not a coder, I can't judge how useful it would be by myself, but I trust your judgement. There does seem to be a demand, and if it helps find those questions more easily, then I'm up for it.

Comment: I'm for it just because seeing the word numpy makes me laugh.

Comment: Does the [tag:mathematics] tag not already serve this purpose?  It seems to me the SE philosophy is that if the question is *about* numpy then it should belong on SO, if it is simply about something that may *use* numpy in Blender, the existing [tag:mathematics] tag should cover it, right?

Comment: _Does   `python` + `mathematics` imply `numpy`_ ?   ( leaving out the  moot point re what maths questions -->  Maths SE :-/)   TBH I'm not 100% sold on the idea of the tag, was talking myself out of it while writing the question.   Arrived  here after writing a question pertaining to blender,  requiring  a `numpy`  solution.  Followed SE philosophy and asked on SO. My conclusion from that adventure:  it is better asked & more helpful here._ie_ , when I find myself, or see others  asking "How to do Bar in Blender using  Foo" often enough, perhaps a Foo tag is worth considering .

Comment: @batFINGER to your first question: no, not necessarily.  But I guess I am struggling to see a scenario where numpy specifically is necessary to be tagged and not mathematics in general.

Comment: I don't think, for the tag, the distinction would lie so much in the maths that `numpy` does, as in the idiom it uses to do it. Is it tricky to find the line between BSE 'Blender Numpy', and SO 'Numpy Numpy?'  BTW, my introduction for beginners has been through Rich Colburn's generous [Numpy for Blender](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLgJKmspCQMIivIdce4P_v4uqCh0f93tax) series of videos.. covers some of that idiom, but doesn't dig into the kind of optimisation question that you've been posing recently.

Comment: Thankyou & agree it's tricky (and sticky) attempting  to find the demarcation.  Will check them out.   Recall the name from my BA days.

Comment: @batFINGER I think you're probably ahead of them.. but a really nice intro for folks like me.

Comment: FWIW I'm in favor. Dealing with Python (notably slow but accessible language) and a software with many lists that can contain many vectorized elements, having easier access to questions / answers about a well maintained and optimized library will definitely help aspiring coders in the long run.

Comment: I'm not a coder, and can't too well judge the usefulness but I don't really see a reason *not* to have it. The SE description of a tag is... `A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other, similar questions. Using the right tags makes it easier for others to find and answer your question.` anyway.. So it would make sense to have the tag if it is going to help other users find the right questions and answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a great idea, and don't see any downsides.

To [I could really use MathJax for a series of qestions - how to build support for it?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2222/5334) the only down side was load time for posts, but this is just a tag.

Numpy is incredibly powerful and can solve a lot of calculation conundrums and provide capabilities that may be useful in surprising ways, but it takes getting used to. Having a `numpy` tag allows readers to quickly find many examples of numpy-based solutions and read through them, and this makes it a lot easer to modify them and explore new uses.

*Yes please!*